# double negation insertion in agda

Tags: logic, proof, agda

I want some clarification on double negations in agda.

even though

```
z≡z : 0 ≡ 0
z≡z = refl
```

I cannot figure out how to prove:

```
¬¬z≡z : (0 ≡ 0 → ⊥) → ⊥
¬¬z≡z ?
```

Which is long hand for `¬ (0 ≢ 0)`.  Perhaps I've missed an agda idiom somewhere along the way.  Idealy I'd like an explanation with minimal reference the standard library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can prove `¬¬z≡z` by

```
¬¬z≡z : (0 ≡ 0 → ⊥) → ⊥
¬¬z≡z h = h refl
```